# Responsive web design - cards in a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to find the term for this responsive gallery animation style. The animation is activated when the user changes the browser size (width). The cards from the right will move to the bottom left while the browser is being adjusted to a smaller size - and cards from the bottom left will move up to the top right when the browser is adjusted to a larger size.

Please refer to the link below for an example:
http://www.mypoorbrain.com/

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The term is "cascading grid"

Check this link for more details : https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Is there a term for the animation for when the cards are positioned from top to bottom and bottom to top? In http://www.mypoorbrain.com/ the cards are shown gliding into position rather than disappearing and appearing into position.

Comment: Try this another package (by the same author as the previous one) : https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ (Layout section) ...DEMO : https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mEinp